# find all words in a text string beginning with $

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python script to parse some text and save all words that start with '$'.

The line of code I am running is:

```
for post in posts
   ticker = re.findall(r'\b[$]\w+', post.title)
   tickers.append([ticker])
```

When I run this script the output is:

```
[[[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]], [[]]]
```

I am thinking there is just an error in my regex expression but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: Looks like there's no matches. Try escaping the `$`. `r'\b\$\w+'` so it matches a literal $ character and not the end of line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). "$" is a special character and marks the end of the string. You have to escape it.

Probably what you're looking for:

```py
ticker = [re.findall(r'\$\w+', post.title) for post in posts]
```

if you want to exclude empty lists/logs

```py
# bool([]) == False
# bool([...]) == True
ticker = list(filter(bool, re.findall(r'\$\w+', post.title) for post in posts))
```

Comment: This seems fix the regular expression however I am still getting empty logs whenever the string does not contain a '$'.

Comment: That's what you're asking for in your original post though. Please update with a sample input and expected output

Comment: I will mark this as correct and just run an additional filter to clean out the empty arrays. Thank you.

Comment: Edited to exclude empty lines